# System.String Type in C#

Tags: c#, clr

I know that it may sound like a weird question but this has been going on in my mind for a while.

I know that the System.String type in C# is actually a class with a constructor that has a character array parameter. For example the following code is legal and causes no error:

```
System.String s = new System.String("Hello".toCharArray());
```

My question is that what makes is possible for the System.String class to accept an array of characters simply this way:

```
System.String s = "Hello";
```

Comment: The compiler team made that possible. Just like other literals, `Nullable<T>`, extension methods, etc.

Comment: Could it be because of the indexer it uses? and if so then how it does that ?

Comment: It's a language construct, just like an `if` statement or the `var` keyword. It's simply how the language works, `string` is a special case to allow for easier use.

Comment: My (naive) guess is that when you look at the compiled IL, creating a string just using the `"Hello"` syntax generates a `ldstr` IL instruction, whereas using the constructor with the array creates instructions that creates the `"Hello"` string in-line, calls the `ToCharArray`, then passes that into the `String` constructor. I would guess that it's an implementation detail of how the CLR uses `ldstr`, but otherwise both of your options there simply produce different IL instructions.

Comment: This is just one example of where the compiler can do things you cannot implement using the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call:

```
System.String s = new System.String("Hello".toCharArray());
```

You are explicitly invoking a constructor

When you write:

```
string foo = "bar";
```

An IL instruction ([Ldstr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr.aspx)) pushes a new object reference to that string literal. It's not the same as calling a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible because the [C# language](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) specifies that string literals are possible (see §2.4.4.5 String literals). The C# compiler and CIL/CLR have good support for how these literals are used, e.g. with the [`ldstr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) opcode.

There is no support for including such literals for your own custom types.

Answer (score -2):

Strings are kind of a special clr type. They are the only immutable reference type.

Here are several things which may help you to understand string type:

```
 var a = "Hello";
 var b = new String("Hello".ToCharArray());
 var c = String.Intern(b); // 'interns' the string...
 var equalsString = a == b;  // true
 var equalsObj =    (object)a == (object)b; // false
 var equalsInterned =    (object)a == (object)c; // true !!

 a[0] = 't'; // not valid, because a string is immutable. Instead, do it this way:
 var array = b.ToArray();
 array[0] = 't';
 a = new String(array); // a is now "tello"
```

Comment: `They are the only immutable reference type.`  What?  Really?  Sorry, but no.  There are *lots* of immutable reference types.  Here's one more: `public class Foo {}`

Comment: @Servy That is immutability by design... strings are immutable because the clr said so, not the programmer.

Comment: First off, there isn't any real difference.  Second, strings aren't even immutable, technically, they're just immutable in their public API.  Internally strings can be, and in certain situations actually are, actually mutated, so obviously immutability is not enforced by the runtime; clearly it allows it.

Comment: I don't see how any of this answers the question.

Comment: @Servy "are actually mutated" ? Never seen that happen (only with pure managed code, I mean).. do you have an example ?

Comment: @Olivier That's the point; you wouldn't see it happen; it is designed such that strings are observably immutable externally.  They are only ever mutated when it can't be observed by a programmer.  The `StringBuilder` implementation (at least through 3.5) actually relied on mutating strings (that were never exposed externally).

Comment: Agreed, native code can mutate strings. Memory is mutable, so strings are, if you see this that way. But you're playing with words. I could also override the vtable pointer of an instance using native code, and pretend that clr polymorphism is broken :/